# what is type of Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Form example I would like to create method that request any TextBox1.text , I write

```
void method(Textbox text)
{ }
```

But when I would like create method that request any dropdownlist, which type should I specify in the method ?

```
void method(Type dropdownlist)
{ }
```

Type= ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its `ASP.Net` I believe you need [DropDownList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
void method(DropDownList dropdownlist)
{
}
```

Remember to include `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`

Comment: I had forgotten namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls.
Ok, thank you.

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you hover over an unknown type, Intellisense will suggest you import a namespace if it knows that class is in a referenced namespace.